# Building official SRPMs in CentOS. All the steps

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm

I am new to Centos and `yum` in general.

1. How do I retreive the SRPM using `yumdownloader --source`? When I run the command it says the SRPMs are not found. How do I add the repository? *I am talking about official CentOS packages here.*
2. Once downloaded, what is the command to unpack the SRPM so I can edit the files?
3. Last, once I am done modifying, what is the command to rebuild the modified source RPM?
4. From a SRPM, how does one create a RPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How do I retreive the SRPM using yumdownloader --source? When I run the command it says the SRPMs are not found. How do I add the repository? I am talking about official CentOS packages here.

This is an issue with CentOS: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=1646

Assuming you're CentOS 5, create this file in /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-SRPMS.repo

```
[base-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
enabled=1

#released updates
[update-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
enabled=1

#packages used/produced in the build but not released
[addons-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
enabled=1

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
enabled=1

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib-SRPMS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib SRPMS
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/SRPMS/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
```

- Once downloaded, what is the command to unpack the SRPM so I can edit the files?

`rpm -ivh your.src.rpm`

This assumes you have necessary directories, if you don't run `mkdir -p /usr/src/redhat/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}` to create them.

The file you'll usually want to edit is the spec file in /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/packagename.spec.

- Last, once I am done modifying, what is the command to rebuild the modified source RPM?

`rpmbuild -bb /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/your.spec` to just build the RPM

`rpmbuild -ba /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/your.spec` to just build the RPM and an SRPM

- From a SRPM, how does one create a RPM?

`rpmbuild --rebuild your.src.rpm`

If you need to build RPMs you should look in to using [mock](https://fedorahosted.org/mock/).

Answer (score 0):

- **[Yum Download Source SRPM on CentOS](http://www.imminentweb.com/technologies/yum-download-source-rpm)**
- **[Using mock to build SRPM on CentOS](http://www.smert.net/2009/04/22/using-mock-to-build-postfix-rpms-with-mysql-support-for-centos/)**

> [centos-src]
>   name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch - Source
>   baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/SRPMS/
>   gpgcheck=1
>   gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

`yumdownloader --source kernel`

`rpm -i kernel-arch.src.rpm`

UPDATE: This is also relevant:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source

> cd /usr/src/redhat/SPECS
>   rpmbuild -bp --target=`uname -m` kernel-2.6.spec